# Explicit computation of projective dimension

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module, dimension-theory-algebra

I want to study the projective dimension $h_p(M)$ of an $A$-module $M,$ which it was defined as the least integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ($0\in\mathbb{N}$) such that exists a projective resolution of length $n$,
$$0\to P^{-n}\to\dots\to P^{-1}\to P^0\to M\to 0.$$
I also know the following characterisation:
$$h_p(M)=\max\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\exists N\in A-\text{mod}, \text{Ext}^n(M,N)\neq0\}$$
I’m not very practical with these things so I would like to find some explicit examples of computation. I have an example, which is the computation of the projective dimension of the projective dimension of the $A$-module $M=\mathbb{C},$ where $$A=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(y^2-x^3)}$$
and with the multiplication by $x$ and $y$ trivial. Where can I find some exercises of this typology or what is the best way to face computations like that I have written?

Comment: A general idea : it's easy to see (or at the very least an interesting exercise) that if $M$ has projective dimension $\leq n$, then for any projective resolution $P^{n-1}\to ... \to P^0 \to M\to 0$, the kernel of $P^{n-1}\to P^{n-2}$ is projective (so adding it to that projective resolution gives one of the form you require). So one method to compute these things when they're easy enough is to just find an easy projective module $P^0$ which surjects onto $M$, then another one $P^1$ onto $\ker(P^0\to M)$ and so on inductively until the kernel is itself projective

Comment: But in your example I suspect the dimension is infinite, and I think you can cook up an infinite projective resolution with first term $A$ and all other terms $A^2$ and then use it to compute some $\mathrm{Ext}$ to check that they're never $0$

Comment: Do you want to consider a projective resolution like $\to A^2\to A^2\to A\to \mathbb{C}\to 0?$ What are the maps? The sequence would be exact

Comment: You should try to come up with the maps yourself, it's a good exercise !

Comment: I try writing the first maps: the map $A\to\mathbb{C}$ should be the projection $\overline{p}\mapsto p(0,0);$ the map $A^2\to A$ should be $(\overline{p},\overline{q})\mapsto \overline{xp+yq},$ right? With these maps I should have the exactness in A and $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: Yes those were the maps I was thinking of, now you can try to compute its kernel and resolve that one

Comment: Yes, that's what I think too : the kernels look similar and I suspect they're actually periodic (though I haven't checked it for sure). In that case, $\mathrm{Ext}$ is periodic too. Computing $\mathrm{Ext}$'s is then easy, you should try to plug in the kernels themselves, or with a bit of luck, $\mathbb C$

Comment: I made an error computing the kernels. I was writing a generic $\overline{p}$ as $\overline{ay+r(x)},$ where $a\in\mathbb{C},$ while in general it should be $\overline{a(x)y+r(x)}.$ Now I don’t know if these kernel are easy to use...